# Why is my python function not being called?

Tags: python, function

I am building a game similar to Space Invaders but with just one villain in each level. The point is that every two seconds the program generates a random number between 1 and 10, if that number is 3,6 or 9, the villain attacks. The function that generates the random number its called every 25 milliseconds, so when this reaches 2000 or any multiple, it generates the random number, but I don't understand why it doesn't it attack when the random number is 3,6 or 9. I am sorry for the dumb question but I am new at this.

```
def attack(self):
    global count
    self.xVel=0
    while self.y+50<=self.canvas.winfo_height():
        count=0
        self.y+=self.yVel
        if self.y+50>=self.canvas.winfo.height():
            while self.y+50<=self.canvas.winfo_height():
                self.y-=self.yVel
                if self.y==8:
                    count==count
                    pass


def update(self):
    global count
    num=0
    self.draw()
    self.x += self.xVel
    count+=25
    if count%2000==0:
       num=random.randint(1,10)
       print(num)
       if num%3==0:
           self.attack

    else:
        if self.x <= 0 or self.x + 50 >= self.canvas.winfo_width():
            self.xVel= -self.xVel
        if self.hp<=0:
            self.dead=True
```

Comment: You have to `call` attack, do `self.attack()`, i.e. add parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But now when the function is called the whole program stops working

Comment: It means you have infinite `while` loop there (inside attack() function), it never finishes. You have to re-think your loop formula to make it always finite.